# Is a SQL Injection Possible using a Java PreparedStatement and a MySQL Stored Routine

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

Java:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = myConnection.prepareStatement("CALL myStoredRoutine(?, ?, ?)");
stmt.setString(1, a);
stmt.setString(2, b);
stmt.setString(3, c);
stmt.executeQuery();
```

---

If my stored routine is in MySQL is it possible for the unfiltered Strings to inject something into my code?

Comment: Basically, no. But it could turn into a possible SQL Injection if your stored procedure builds a dynamic sql statement and execute it.

Comment: Lets say you have this query `SELECT * FROM userTable WHERE userName = ?`. If your're using a `preparedStatement`, it's sent to the database directly where it's compiled and then `userName` from the `setString()` method would be substituted. If it finds an illegal value, it will cause an exception to be thrown. `userName` like `' or '1'='1` will be treated as a whole string and not as a statement involving operators like `or` and `=`. Therefore, it's safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as `PreparedStatement` was build to protect against `SQL Injection`.

I see you're calling a stored procedure so better use `CallableStatement`.

```
String SQL = "{CALL myStoredRoutine(?, ?, ?)}";
CallableStatement cstmt = myConnection.prepareCall(SQL);
```

- **Prepared Statement**

Instances of PreparedStatement contain an SQL statement that has already been compiled. This is what makes a statement "prepared"

Because PreparedStatement objects are precompiled, their execution can be faster than that of Statement objects.

The prepared statement is used to execute sql queries

- **Callable Statement**

A CallableStatement object provides a way to call stored procedures in a standard way for all RDBMSs. A stored procedure is stored in a database; the call to the stored procedure is what a CallableStatement object contains.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. The strings **are** filtered by the prepared statement. That's one of their points, actually.

Answer (score 0):

No. The purpose of parameter binding is that parameters are parsed as parameters. Thats good for performance as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you use parametrized queries, arguments are parsed and converted with escape characters if required hence not possible. That is the advantange of using parametrized query/prepared statements.